# Bound Dropdown List not populating into sql table on save

Tags: sql, asp.net, stored-procedures, crud

I have two dropdownlists that are bound to two columns in a sql table1.  When I select an item within the dropdownlists and click my save button, the text in the dropdownlist does not appear in the sql table2.

The textbox data as well as the other dropdownlists that are not bound to a sql table, are saving into my sql table2.

I am using a stored procedure in sql to save the data from my webform to sql.

Stored Procedure:

```
USE [OnCallWeb]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[DispatchRolesCreateOrUpdate]    Script Date: 6/8/2023 10:10:04 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROC [dbo].[DispatchRolesCreateOrUpdate]
@ID int,
@Name nvarchar(max),
@Position nvarchar(max),
@Roles nvarchar(max),
@Status nvarchar(max),
@DispatcherCovering nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
IF(@ID=0)
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Dispatcher_Roles(Name,Position,Roles,Status,DispatcherCovering)
    VALUES(@Name,@Position,@Roles,@Status,@DispatcherCovering)
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
    UPDATE Dispatcher_Roles
    SET
        Name = @Name,
        Position = @Position,
        Roles = @Roles,
        Status = @Status,
        DispatcherCovering = @DispatcherCovering
    Where ID= @ID
    END

END
```

My CS code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace OnCallWeb.Dispatch_Policies
{
    public partial class WorkstationRoles : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=UCPDAPPS2;Initial Catalog=OnCallWeb;Integrated Security=true;");
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Reporting_SystemConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);
            string sqlquery = "select [ID],[Emp_ID] + '  ' + [Emp_Name] as FullName from [dbo].[Personnel] where [JurisdictionID] = 99";
            SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn);
            sqlconn.Open();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcomm);
            sda.Fill(ds);
            DropDownList1.DataSource = ds;
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "FullName";
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "ID";
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
            DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", "0"));
            DropDownList4.DataSource = ds;
            DropDownList4.DataTextField = "FullName";
            DropDownList4.DataValueField = "ID";
            DropDownList4.DataBind();
            DropDownList4.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", "0"));
            sqlconn.Close();


            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                btnDelete.Enabled = false;
            }
         }

        protected void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Clear();
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            ID.Value = "";
            DropDownList1.Items.Clear();
            DropDownList2.Items.Clear();
            TextBox1.Text = "";
            DropDownList3.Items.Clear();
            DropDownList4.Items.Clear();
            lblSuccessMessage.Text = lblErrorMessage.Text = "";
            btnSave.Text = "Save";
            btnDelete.Enabled = false;
            
        }

        protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (sqlcon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                sqlcon.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("DispatchRolesCreateOrUpdate",sqlcon);
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID",(ID.Value==""?0:Convert.ToInt32(ID.Value)));
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name",DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Position",DropDownList2.Text.Trim());
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Roles",TextBox1.Text.Trim());
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status",DropDownList3.Text.Trim());
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DispatcherCovering",DropDownList4.SelectedItem.Text);
            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlcon.Close();
            Clear();
            if (ID.Value == "")
                lblSuccessMessage.Text = "Saved Successfully";
            else
                lblSuccessMessage.Text = "Updated Successfully";
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried changing the addwithvalues SelectedItem.Text to SelectedItem.Value which did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer?

You have to place your FIRST time page load code, the code that loads + set's up the dropdown lists inside of the !IsPostBack.

Remember, on any button click, or even controls with autopostback = true, then a page post back occurs.

So, in your case, page load runs, dropdowns are loaded up.

When a user clicks a button, page load will fire again, and then your button stub code runs.

However, since on page load, you re-load the dropdown controls again, then the user's choice will be lost.

So place your down down list "loading" code inside of the REAL first page load (inside of the !IsPostBack code stub, since then the dropdown lists will not be re-loaded each page post-back).

Thus, the user choices and values will not be over-write each time a button is clicked.

You should also go project->settings, and use the wizards to create your connection string.

Eg here:

[image]

So, with above knowledge in mind, and my suggesting to remove the connection string stuff out of code (since it will be rather difficult to change all those hard coded connection strings in code), then I suggest this code:

And I have a global (static) class with my helper routines, they are this:

```
    public static DataTable MyRstP(SqlCommand cmdSQL)
    {
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (cmdSQL)
            {
                cmdSQL.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        return rstData;
    }
    public static void MyRstE(SqlCommand cmdSQL)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (cmdSQL)
            {
                cmdSQL.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

So, I have ONE location for the connection and even the use of the SQL command object. (not only is this nice and and handy while coding, it also means you can easy change the connection string at deployment time).

So, now your code becomes this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadData();
            btnDelete.Enabled = false;

        }
    }

    void LoadData()
    {
        string sqlquery 
            = @"select [ID],[Emp_ID] + '  ' + [Emp_Name] as FullName from 
               [dbo].[Personnel] where [JurisdictionID] = 99";

        SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(sqlquery);
        DataTable dt = General.MyRstP(cmdSQL);
        DropDownList1.DataSource = dt;
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "FullName";
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "ID";
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", "0"));

        DropDownList4.DataSource = dt;
        DropDownList4.DataTextField = "FullName";
        DropDownList4.DataValueField = "ID";
        DropDownList4.DataBind();
        DropDownList4.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", "0"));
    }

    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("DispatchRolesCreateOrUpdate");
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (ID.Value == "" ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(ID.Value));
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =  DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Position", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =  DropDownList2.Text.Trim();
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Roles", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;  
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =  DropDownList3.Text;
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@DispatcherCovering",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =  DropDownList4.SelectedItem.Text);
        General.MyRstE(sqlCmd);

        if (ID.Value == "")
            lblSuccessMessage.Text = "Saved Successfully";
        else
            lblSuccessMessage.Text = "Updated Successfully";
    }
```

So, check the !IsPostBack. You can only load ONE time and on FIRST page load the dropdown controls. If you re-load dropdown's each time as you have, then the user's selections will be lost on each post-back.

## Edit: Different connection strings are required.

Since you have to deal with MORE then one connection string, then I suggest this code for the 2 helper routines:

```
    public static DataTable MyRstP(SqlCommand cmdSQL, string sCon = "")
    {
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
        if (sCon == "")
            sCon = Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4;

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (cmdSQL)
            {
                cmdSQL.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        return rstData;
    }
    public static void MyRstE(SqlCommand cmdSQL, string sCon = "")
    {
        if (sCon == "")
            sCon = Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4;

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sCon))
        {
            using (cmdSQL)
            {
                cmdSQL.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

So, now, for 99% of your code, then you can/have/use/enjoy the main overall connection for the given database.

HOWEVER, now, for cases in which you want to use a different connection, then you can go

```
  MyRstE(cmdSQL,Properties.Settings.Default.MyOtherDB)
```

Comment: Thanks for that detailed information.   I've never used postbacks so I can see why I am messing up.  I made all the changes you requested and I am now getting that the General.MyRstP(cmdSQL) does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Well, if you going to place the 2 "helper routines" MyRstP and MyRstE in the same code behind module, then remove the General. Prefix. I had assumed that since these are re-usable routines, you would create a static class (Genreal) in this example. After all, we not going to type such code over and over and create world poverty here, right? So, if you for now and testing placed MyRstP and MyRstE in the SAME code behind, then remove the General. prefix  in the code (and just use MyRstP/MyRstP in your code). . Either way, you need those 2 helper routines in code behind.

Comment: In regards to post-backs? Any button click or ANY control on the page that has code behind will in fact trigger a post back. And that means page load runs FIRST and THEN your code behind stub runs.  So, the simple result of this knowledge is that page load will fire and run a LOT of times in a typical page, and thus for setup code, and code to load up things, you want such code to ONLY run the first time and on the first real page load event, and after that, such code will not run each time a button on the page is clicked (which of course triggers a post-back). Hence need for !IsPostBack check

Comment: Again,  thanks for the detailed info.  I removed the "General and just left them as MyRstP and MyRstE but this caused a new error "Invalid object name dbo.Personnel" on the line "rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExceuteReader());"   That dbo is in a different table on a different server and is where I get the data for Dropdownlist1 and Dropdownlist4.  I did add connections to both servers under the settings for the webpage and I set MyRstP to the server for the dropdowns and MyRstE to the server saving the new data from my webpage thinking that was the issue but did not resolve the new error.

Comment: Well, either you sql is wrong, or the conneciton is wrong. I mean, fire up SSMS, paste in your select query - make sure it works. So, nuts and bolts issues like ensuring a working valid connection and things like valid SQL or a valid table name? That's really just some basic work you want to check.  The error message seems rather clear - the table Personnel does not exist with the given connection you are using

Comment: See my 2nd edit. I show some suggestions as to how to deal with more then one database, but STILL use those 2 helper routines.

Comment: I checked the connection settings and it works so that is not the issue.  But I thank you for all your help on this.

Comment: Well, you certainly don't have to use those 2 helper routines, they are just to save the keyboard, since you will in code have to do such operations over and over - it stands to reason to have a few routines here and there to help you. And such basic coding skills will be required for any project, and without as such, you will struggle here. It's not clear at all why such code is not working for you, but finding out why will yield fruit in the future for you. I assume in settings when you build the connections , and test connection works for you?